# Integral form of Taylor’s remainder $R_k(x) = f(x) - P_k(x)$ for functions with $k$ continuous derivatives only

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

Michael Steele wrote on page 112 of his book “Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications” that if $f$ has a continuous second derivative, then the Taylor’s formula with remainder gives that for all real $x$ and $y$:

$$f(y) - f(x) = (y-x)f’(x) + \frac 12 (y-x)^2f’’(x) + r(x,y),$$

where the remainder term $r(x,y)$ is given by

$$r(x,y) = \int_x^y (y-u)(f’’(u)-f’’(x))\,du.$$

Is it possible to deduce this from the integral form

$$r(x,y) = \int_x^y \frac{(y-u)^2}{2}f’’’(u)\,du,$$

which is proved on Wikipedia? And is it possible to do so assuming only that $f’’$ is continuous but not necessarily absolutely continuous?

Comment: Integration by parts will give you what you are after.

Comment: As for the restriction to $C^2$ functions; my suggestion would be approximate such a function by $C^3$ functions such that the second derivatives converge uniformly and take the limit. I'd be surprised if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts yields
$$\begin{align}r(x,y) &= \int_x^y \frac{(y-u)^2}{2}f’’’(u)\,du=f''(u)\frac{(y-u)^2}{2}\Big|^y_x+\int^y_x(y-u)f''(u)\,du\\
&=-f''(x)\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}+\int^y_x(y-u)f''(u)\,du\\
&=-f''(x)\int^y_x (y-u)\,du+\int^y_x(y-u)f''(u)\,du\\
&=\int^y_x(y-u)(f''(u)-f''(x))\,dy
\end{align}$$

Notice that
$$\int^y_x(y-u)\,du\stackrel{v=y-u}{=}-\int^0_{y-x}v\,dv=-\frac{v^2}{2}\Big|^0_{y-x}=\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}$$